# how to implement search functionality in Gridview in android

Tags: android, search, gridview, android-edittext

In my application I have search tab which display images with their name in grid view and now I want to implement search functionality. I have been searching in google for past two days but I didn't get any solution. Any idea or tutorial 0r how can I achieve this?

Anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

mainactivity

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.example.diceapp.R;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity 
{


     JSONArray results;

     JSONObject jobj;

     SearchCustomAdapter adapter1;

     ImageButton ib;

     ArrayList<String> a1,a2,a3,a4;

     ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<String>();

     ArrayList<String> description=new ArrayList<String>();

     ArrayList<String> image=new ArrayList<String>();

     ArrayList<String> price=new ArrayList<String>();

     Button add;

     String pid;

     GridView gView;

     EditText src;

     int textlength = 0;

     ArrayList<String> p_name = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> p_image = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

        a1=new ArrayList<String>();

        a2=new ArrayList<String>();

        a3=new ArrayList<String>();

        a4=new ArrayList<String>();

        src=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.srcetxt);

        /*src.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                SearchActivity.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(cs);  
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
            }
        });*/

        new Searchtask().execute();

        gView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("outside on click"+position);

            }
        });

       ib=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    }

    private class Searchtask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> 
    {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data ...");

            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
        {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http:link.php");

            return json;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
        {

            System.out.println("---------------return name list json------------"+json);

            pDialog.dismiss();

            try 
            {
                jobj=json.getJSONObject("response");
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                results = jobj.getJSONArray("obejects");

                System.out.println("In product Activity after JSON");
                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    name.add(c.getString("name"));

                    image.add(c.getString("image"));

                     price.add(c.getString("price"));

                    description.add(c.getString("Description"));

                }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter1  = new SearchCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.gridlistimg, name, image,description,price);

            gView.setAdapter(adapter1);

        }
    }

}
```

baseadapter class

```
package com.example.diceapp.search;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.example.diceapp.AAAMainActivity;
import com.example.diceapp.R;
import com.example.diceapp.category.ImageLoader;

public class SearchCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ArrayList<String> aaaa1,bbbb1,cccc1;


    ArrayList<String> c_pname;

    ArrayList<String> c_pimage;

    ArrayList<String> c_pprice;

    ArrayList<String> c_pdescription;

    String[] data_text;
    String[] data_image;

    ImageLoader iloader;

    public SearchCustomAdapter(Context c, int productDescribe,ArrayList<String> pname, ArrayList<String> pimage,
            ArrayList<String> productdescription, ArrayList<String> pprice)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub



        this.context=c;

        this.c_pname=pname;

        this.c_pprice=pprice;

        this.c_pdescription=productdescription;

        this.c_pimage=pimage;

         inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         iloader= new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());


    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return c_pname.size();
        //return data_text.length;
    }

@Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return  c_pname.indexOf(getItem(pos));//arg0;
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row=convertView; 

        ViewHolder vh;

        if(row==null)
        {
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_activity, parent, false);

            vh=new ViewHolder();

            vh.pname=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);

            vh.pprice=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            vh.image1=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            vh.btn=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.p_custom_tv);


            /*row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                     System.out.println("outside on click"+position);


                     ArrayList<String> sendingary=new ArrayList<String>();

                     sendingary.add(c_pname.get(position));

                     sendingary.add(c_pprice.get(position));

                     sendingary.add(c_pimage.get(position));

                     sendingary.add(c_pdescription.get(position));

                     Intent cp=new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),product_details.class);

                     cp.putStringArrayListExtra("aryvalue", sendingary);

                     cp.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                     context.startActivity(cp);

                }
            });*/

            row.setTag(vh);
        }
        else 
        {
            vh = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            row=convertView;
        }

        vh.pname.setText(c_pname.get(position));
        vh.pprice.setText("KD "+c_pprice.get(position));        
        iloader.DisplayImage(c_pimage.get(position),  vh.image1);

        return row;
    }



    public static class ViewHolder
    {
         TextView pname,pprice;

         ImageView image1;

         Button btn;
    }

    public SearchCustomAdapter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you did so far post the code

Comment: I have implemented using base adapter.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I  have posted the question, have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I just edit your code please replace and check it

**SearchActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    JSONArray results;

    JSONObject jobj;

    SearchCustomAdapter adapter1;

    ImageButton ib;

    ArrayList<String> a1, a2, a3, a4;

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> image = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();

    Button add;

    String pid;

    GridView gView;

    EditText src;

    int textlength = 0;

    ArrayList<String> p_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> p_image = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);

        a1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        a2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        a3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        a4 = new ArrayList<String>();

        src = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.srcetxt);

        src.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                if (src.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    applySearch(src.getText().toString().trim());
                } else {
                    adapter1.setC_pname(name);
                    adapter1.setC_pdescription(description);
                    adapter1.setC_pimage(image);
                    adapter1.setC_pprice(price);
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });

        new Searchtask().execute();

        gView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        gView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("outside on click" + position);

            }
        });

        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    }

    private class Searchtask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data ...");

            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http:link.php");

            return json;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            System.out.println("---------------return name list json------------" + json);

            pDialog.dismiss();

            try {
                jobj = json.getJSONObject("response");
                // Getting Array of Contacts
                results = jobj.getJSONArray("obejects");

                System.out.println("In product Activity after JSON");
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = results.getJSONObject(i);

                    name.add(c.getString("name"));

                    image.add(c.getString("image"));

                    price.add(c.getString("price"));

                    description.add(c.getString("Description"));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter1 = new SearchCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.gridlistimg, name, image, description, price);

            gView.setAdapter(adapter1);

        }
    }

    private void applySearch(String searchStr) {
        ArrayList<String> searchname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> searchdescription = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> searchimage = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> searchprice = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
            if (name.get(i).contains(searchStr)) {
                searchname.add(name.get(i));
                searchdescription.add(description.get(i));
                searchimage.add(image.get(i));
                searchprice.add(price.get(i));
            }
        }

        adapter1.setC_pname(searchname);
        adapter1.setC_pdescription(searchdescription);
        adapter1.setC_pimage(searchimage);
        adapter1.setC_pprice(searchprice);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**SearchCustomAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    ArrayList<String> aaaa1, bbbb1, cccc1;

    ArrayList<String> c_pname;
    ArrayList<String> c_pprice;
    ArrayList<String> c_pdescription;
    ArrayList<String> c_pimage;

    public void setC_pname(ArrayList<String> c_pname) {
        this.c_pname = c_pname;
    }

    public void setC_pimage(ArrayList<String> c_pimage) {
        this.c_pimage = c_pimage;
    }

    public void setC_pprice(ArrayList<String> c_pprice) {
        this.c_pprice = c_pprice;
    }

    public void setC_pdescription(ArrayList<String> c_pdescription) {
        this.c_pdescription = c_pdescription;
    }

    String[] data_text;
    String[] data_image;

    ImageLoader iloader;

    public SearchCustomAdapter(Context c, int productDescribe, ArrayList<String> pname, ArrayList<String> pimage, ArrayList<String> productdescription, ArrayList<String> pprice) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = c;

        this.c_pname = pname;

        this.c_pprice = pprice;

        this.c_pdescription = productdescription;

        this.c_pimage = pimage;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        iloader = new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return c_pname.size();
        // return data_text.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return c_pname.indexOf(getItem(pos));//arg0;
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;

        ViewHolder vh;

        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_activity, parent, false);

            vh = new ViewHolder();

            vh.pname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);

            vh.pprice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            vh.image1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            vh.btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.p_custom_tv);

            /*
             * row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             * 
             * @Override public void onClick(View arg0) {
             * 
             * System.out.println("outside on click"+position);
             * 
             * 
             * ArrayList<String> sendingary=new ArrayList<String>();
             * 
             * sendingary.add(c_pname.get(position));
             * 
             * sendingary.add(c_pprice.get(position));
             * 
             * sendingary.add(c_pimage.get(position));
             * 
             * sendingary.add(c_pdescription.get(position));
             * 
             * Intent cp=new
             * Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),product_details.class);
             * 
             * cp.putStringArrayListExtra("aryvalue", sendingary);
             * 
             * cp.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             * 
             * context.startActivity(cp);
             * 
             * } });
             */

            row.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            row = convertView;
        }

        vh.pname.setText(c_pname.get(position));
        vh.pprice.setText("KD " + c_pprice.get(position));
        iloader.DisplayImage(c_pimage.get(position), vh.image1);

        return row;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView pname, pprice;

        ImageView image1;

        Button btn;
    }

}
```

Comment: i have facing same problem for grid view in my application this is very nice code Thank You @Biraj

Answer (score 6):

If you use ArrayAdapter as your gridview's adapter, you can override [getFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getFilter%28%29) method and return your own Filter, which is able to filter items according to entered text. See e.g. [this link](http://software-workshop.eu/content/android-development-creating-custom-filter-listview) to learn how to work with Filter. Good luck. :-)

Comment: No problem :-) if you dont use ArrayAdapter, you can make your adapter implement "Filterable" interface - then you will be able to call getFiler()