# How to add a search function to gridView on android app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I currently have a simple add that displays news articles from a url in a gridview. I have added a search icon to my main menu xml but i dont know how to get the search function to work. I just need it to display the relevant articles if the string the user searches is in the article title. Any help would be appreciated, I don't know how to get started!

I have other files of course, let me know if you need to see them, i'm not sure what is helpful.

ActivityMain.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<NewsRecord> newsListData = new ArrayList<NewsRecord>();

private GridView newsListView;

private NewsListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

GridView newsListView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.newsFeedList);

adapter = new NewsListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_news_list,  newsListData, this);

newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClicked);

nextStart = 0;
updateListData(nextStart, 20);
}

public int nextStart = 0;

public void updateListData(int StartPoint, int count){
String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getList.php?    start=" + StartPoint + "&count=" + count;

EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();

JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, listener, errorListener);
app.requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);

nextStart +=count;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="About"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:title="Search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
android:textColor="#FFF"
/>

</menu>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/newsListItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
android:id="@+id/newsFeedList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:numColumns="2"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement search functionality in Gridview in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859756/how-to-implement-search-functionality-in-gridview-in-android)

Comment: i'm not really sure what the baseadapter is in this example, do i need to create one? or do i just change the adapter I currently have?

Comment: Finding the above example too complicated, not sure what I need to use and what I don't. If anyone could help/explain, that would be amazing!